Bayesian disease probabilities
Question: 1% of all individuals in a certain population are carriers of a particular disease. A diagnostic test for this disease has a 98% detection rate for carriers and a 3% detection rate for noncarriers. Suppose the test for this disease is applied independently to two different blood samples from the same randomly selected individual.
To find P(2 positives), why can we not do P(1 positive)^2, where we can find P(1 positive) as a total probability of P(1 positive & disease) + P(1 positive & no disease)? I don't exactly understand the reasoning that "the problem here is that the two tests are not absolutely independent, only conditionally independent given that the individual tested is a carrier or given he or she is not a carrier". Is there a more formal way to see why we can't square the probability?
I am interested in knowing what goes wrong in the squaring approach.

The key here is the phrasing: ".... from the same random selected individual".  That individual's disease state remains the same in each test.   It's the same reasoning as for the results from twice tossing the same randomly selected biased coin, not being absolutely independent.

Why does it matter that the same person is taking the second test, if the tests are independent? For a biased coin that gives 60% heads (with the same biased coin), wouldn't the probability of two heads just be 0.6 * 0.6? Similarly then, shouldn't P(2 positive) = P(1 positive) * P(1 positive).

They are "independent ... for the same person." is another way to say "conditionally independent ... given that person".   For the biased coin: suppose you have two biased coins, one $60%$ heads, one $20%$, and you pick one out at random to toss twice.  The probability for getting two heads from twice tossing the same selected coin is $\mathsf P(2H)=0.5((0.6)^2+(0.2)^2)=0.2$, which is not $(0.5(0.6+0.2))^2 = 0.16$ (the probability for two heads from tosses of two independent selections from the coins).

Saying "independently ... for the same person," is another way to express that the events are "conditionally independent given that person".
The person's disease state, although unknown, is the same during both tests, so biases them both to the same degree.

If the person is a carrier, then both tests have a 98% detection rate.
Where as if the person is a non-carrier, then both tests have a 3% false positive rate.

Therefore, the correct approach is to partition the event over the two states then apply the factorisation for conditional independence of the test given those states.
$$\small\begin{align}\mathsf P(T_1, T_2) &= \mathsf P(T_1,T_2, D)+\mathsf P(T_1,T_2,D^\complement)&&\text{Law of Total Population}\\&=\mathsf P(T_1\mid D)\,\mathsf P(T_2\mid D)\,\mathsf P(D)+\mathsf P(T_1\mid D^\complement)\,\mathsf P(T_2\mid D^\complement)\,\mathsf P(D^\complement)&&\text{conditional independence}\\&= (0.98)^2(0.01)+(0.03)^2(0.99)\\&=0.010495\end{align}$$

Whereas if we had tests for two different individuals, we could consider the tests absolutely independent, and so the approach would be to partition after the factorisation.
$$\small\begin{align}\mathsf P(T_1,T_2) &=\mathsf P(T_1)\,\mathsf P(T_2) \\ &= \left(\mathsf P(D_1)\,\mathsf P(T_1\mid D_1)+\mathsf P(D_1^\complement)\,\mathsf P(T_1\mid D_1^\complement)\right)\!\!\left(\mathsf P(D_2)\,\mathsf P(T_2\mid D_2)+\mathsf P(D_2^\complement)\,\mathsf P(T_2\mid D_2^\complement)\right)\\&=\bigl((0.01)(0.98)+(0.99)(0.03)\bigr)^2\\&=0.00156025\end{align}$$


Alternatively, it would help to understand what assumption is being broken if we apply the method for two different individuals to the conditional probability approach for the same individual.

Notice that the extra terms in the expansion are for when the independent people have different disease states; which cannot occur when they are actually the same person.
$$\small\begin{align}\mathsf P(T_1,T_2) &= \left(\mathsf P(T_1, D_1)+\mathsf P(T_1, D_1^\complement)\right)\!\!\left(\mathsf P(T_2,D_2)+\mathsf P(T_2, D_2^\complement)\right)\\&=\mathsf P(D_1,T_1)\mathsf P(D_2,T_2)+\mathsf P(D_1,T_1)\mathsf P(D_2^\complement,T_2)+\mathsf P(D_1^\complement,T_1)\mathsf P(D_2,T_2)+\mathsf P(D_1^\complement,T_1)\mathsf P(D_2^\complement,T_2)\end{align}$$

I see now that the two methods (independent and conditionally independent) result in different computations, but I am trying to get a intuitive understanding for why? As in, why does conditional independence mean you must partition first. Or, conversely, why is it wrong to not partition, and just multiply together first.

Alternatively, it would help to understand what assumption is being broken if we apply the method for two different individuals to the conditional probability approach for the same individual.

@user15141432  I've added a explanation.
